# Unable to submit more than 20 file type fields in single form submit?

Tags: php, html, forms, input-type-file

I have to submit 50-100 files in single form submit. I put file types for them but I am getting only 20 files other are not submitting.

Is there any limit in form submission regarding number of file type in a single form submit?

If yes then how can I submit them in single submit?

Comment: It would be easier to analyze with some code appended.

Comment: it has massive line of code as there are approx 50-6- fields fields in a form. You can check from here
http://ds211.projectstatus.co.uk/pep_audit/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 'max_file_upload' in your php.ini

```
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

OR

place this in top of your script

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads', 50);
```

Answer (score -2):

use max_file_uploads or change it in php.ini file